# How to block UIGestureRecognizer's behind an overlay view?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have a complex view hierarchy with all sorts of `UIGestureRecognizer`'s.

I then present an overlay `UIView` and if the user interacts with this overlay, I do **not** want any gesture recognizers to fire that were placed *underneath* that overlay. Currently, for example, dragging causes gesture recognizers to fire beneath the overlay view to fire.

I would like to avoid any solution that leads to potential spaghetti code (ex. iterating through the view hierarchy and disabling gesture recognizers).

Similar question(s):

- [Need to block all touches except for specific one in an overlay view for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808198/need-to-block-all-touches-except-for-specific-one-in-an-overlay-view-for-ios?rq=1)
- [How to disable touch input to all views except the top-most view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404856/how-to-disable-touch-input-to-all-views-except-the-top-most-view)

Comment: Obvious question: What did you try? Please search, I'm almost sure this has been discussed/answered here multiple times.

Comment: @meaning-matters Surprisingly, I could not find any reasonably clean answer for this question. As for what I tried, might be unpopular, but I purposefully left that out to not bias answers; as a result of your request, I posted a potential answer below as to not pollute the question space (again, might be unpopular, sorry!). I am just looking to see what creative answers others have, as I could not find any clean answers elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The only kind-of-clean solution I can think of is adding all types of gesture recognizers on the overlay view so those get fired instead of the ones beneath.

For example:

```
overlayView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: nil, action: nil))
overlayView.addGestureRecognizer(UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: nil, action: nil))
overlayView.addGestureRecognizer(UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: nil, action: nil))
```